# Node javascript syntax: what does it mean : '(res) =>'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could please someone explain me the syntax from nodejs docs,
I don't understand  the line:
`(res) => {`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

`(res) => {}` is a fat arrow function. Similar to `function(res) {}` with one big difference, `this` is scoped differently.

in ES6 the fat arrow function was introduce and pretty much does two things to my understanding:

1) It makes the syntax more concise, less stuff to type

2) It lets the `this` reference stay as a reference to the function's parent.

Read up more about lambda unctions [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions)

Answer (score 1):

`(res) => { ... }` is the ES6/ES2015 syntax for anonymous functions.  It is called [arrow functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/).

e.g. 
`var add = function (x, y) { return x + y; }`

...can now be written as:

`var add = (x, y) => { return x + y; }`

...but if it has just one line and that line is a return statement, you can write it as:

`var add = (x, y) => x + y`

These fat arrow functions preserve the lexical scope of `this`, so there are [times when NOT to use arrow functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/) though.  Typically, these are situations when you are declaring a function that depends on the `this` reference to be something other than the `this` context that you are declaring the function in.